# Error when trying to read columns from a text file

Tags: python-2.7

I have a text file of three columns of data, I want to take each column from the text file and save that column as an array so I can use it for plotting graphs.

I have written the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#read file
text_file = open('Test1_data.txt', 'r')
lines = text_file.readlines()
text_file.close()

time = []
real = []
imag = []

for line in lines:
    s = line.split
    time.append(s[0])
    real.append(s[1])
    imag.append(s[2])

time_array = np.array(time)
real_array = np.array(real)
imag_array = np.array(imag)
```

However when I run my code, I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 
'__getitem__'
```

I've tried looking for a solution but am a bit overwhelmed, could anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not calling `split()` but just assigning `s` to the function `lines.split`. fix:

```
s = line.split()
```

Comment: Exactly. If you use the linenumber in the error message, you see the offending line, and then you can use `print` or the debugger to see what `s` is at that point, and you will see <built-in method split of str object at 0x7f67778eab70>.